# Question: What does "nonzero" polynomial mean?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

What does "nonzero" polynomial mean?

Thank you

Comment: This is actually a legitimate question (albeit a bit short). Is a polinomial zero if all coefficients are zero or it evaluates to zero for every value of the underlying ring? (The first is the case)

Comment: A non-zero polynomial is a polynomial with at least one non-zero coefficient - that is, it is not the zero element of the polynomial ring. A non-zero polynomial function is one that evaluates to a non-zero value at some element of its domain.

Comment: Do you know abstract algebra, esp. the distinction: *formal* polynomials vs. polynomial *functions*? What is the source/context of the question?

Comment: @KeyIdeas If he didn't know *any* abstract algebra, then he'd almost certainly be talking about real or complex polynomials, in which case the two definitions are equivalent. :)

Comment: @Thomas Some students encounter polynomials over $\,\Bbb Z/n\,$ before they learn abstract algebra, e.g. in elementary number theory courses. For example, such folks often pose questions about the AKS primality test, and other examples of polynomial arithmetic over finite rings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there is no answer, here is what I stated in the comments:

Usually, a nonzero polynomial $f$ is a polynomial of where not every coefficient is zero, i.e.
$$f(X)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kX^k\quad(n\ge0)$$
and one of the $a_i\neq 0$.

Depending on context, even the definition that $f(x)\neq0$ for some $x$ could be used, however this is rare.

It might seem as if these were equivalent, however consider
$$f(X)=X^2+X$$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. For $0$, it obviously evaluates to zero, for $1$ it is $f(1)=1^2+1=1+1=0$ (because $1+1=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$).

This polynomial is zero regarding the second definition, not regarding the first definition however.

Therefore, the first definition is almost always used.